# how to remove an element when textarea is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if the `textarea` is empty and then remove the element `prev()` to it. How do I do so? My attempt was this:

```
if($(".inputs").val().length == 0){
  $(this).prev().hide();
};
```

Do I have to check for "keypress"? The element I am trying to hide was `show()` after a "keypress" event. But I want to hide it immediately if the `textarea` is empty.

Edit: Question 2: I was using this code to show an element after first input:

```
 $(".inputs").one("keypress", function(){
   $(this).prev().show().addClass("animated slideInUp");
 });
```

but now that I want to hide and show depending on the length of the textarea should I do something like this:

```
  $(".inputs").on("input", function() {
if ($(".inputs").val().length == 0) {
  $(this).prev().hide();
}
else if ($(".inputs").val().length == 1) {
  $(this).prev().show().addClass("animated slideInUp");
}
```

Comment: *Do I have to check for "keypress"?*, it depends. Do if want to check on keypress, then yes.

Comment: But when do you want to check if the textarea is empty? I think the best event listener to add would be either `change` or `oninput` but this all depends when you want/expect the Javascript/jQuery to run to hide/show "the element"

Comment: Are you trying to "remove" or "hide" the element? You've said both things in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the previous element when you delete content within the `<textarea>`, then `.keyup` is the way to go:

```js
$(".inputs").on("input", function() {
  if ($(".inputs").val().length == 0) {
    $(this).prev().hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Hidden when all content is deleted, doesn't restore</div>
<textarea class="inputs"></textarea>
```

Keep in mind that this won't **restore** the previous element when you start typing again. If you'd like to do that, you'll need to extend the script a little to also `.show()` the previous element:

```js
$(".inputs").on("input", function() {
  if ($(".inputs").val().length == 0) {
    $(this).prev().hide();
  }
  else {
    $(this).prev().show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Hidden when all content is deleted, restores</div>
<textarea class="inputs"></textarea>
```

Note that `input` is used over `keyup` in case the user edits the field without using the keyboard.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `.on('input', ...` would be better than `.keyup(...`

Comment: You edited to use `.on()`, but I think Patrick's point was that the `input` event is better than the `keyup` event for this (because the user may edit the field without using the keyboard).

Comment: I thought about writing pretty much the same thing but since the question didn't really give much detail I avoided it, great answer though. I would've used the `input` event over `keyup`.... But still +1 for offering a solution and good detail with such limited detail in the question.

Comment: If you want to use `.input(...)` instead of `.on('input', ...)` you can always monkey-patch jQuery with `$.fn.input = function input() {
  var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply(['input'], arguments)
 return this.on.apply(this, args)
}`

Comment: @EarthyAriyapinyopas -- Awesome! Glad to hear this solution helps you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge okay, just did! Also, I want to ask a follow up question. Should I ask here?

Comment: @EarthyAriyapinyopas -- Generally you should [**ask a new question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), unless you just need a very small clarification on the existing answer, which can be answered in a single comment. You can reference [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752382/2341603) in the new question if it helps, by clicking on the 'Share' link at the bottom of the answer. Also, remember you can [**search**](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for existing answers that are similar -- with over 17 million questions, someone's probably had a similar problem  :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge okay. I posted a new edit for now. Is it okay if you take a quick look at it for me?

Comment: @EarthyAriyapinyopas -- Assuming you have CSS classes called `animated` and `slideInUp`, that will apply the classes whenever there is one character. Note that `== 1` will trigger whenever there's one character after the keyup, including when you delete the second character (which is probably unintentional). You'd be better chaining in into the simple `else` as in my answer, which is only triggered when the user types their first character. Although, again, that's really something that should be a separate question (note that you even said 'Question 2' in your edit) :)